# honda crv 98 idle too low and rough and eventual stall but ok when driving

Tags: honda, sparkplugs, rough-idle, power-loss, spark-plug-wires

(Excuse my english) My dad gave me a **'98 honda crv**. since it came from being serviced after an oil pump failure, it has no power when it's cold I have to press the gas until the engine warms up. I have taken it to various mechanics but they can't find the problem, they only increased the idle power (It uses a lot more gas). I have replaced all the sparkplugs twice to no avail. The only thing I have noticed is that, whenever you remove the sparkplugs' ignition wire and the engine is ON, it will react (losing power) to only three, but not to the last one. it's as if that sparkplug is not contributing any power to the engine.

Any solution that doesn't involve changing the whole engine?

Comment: Sounds like it's down a cylinder

Comment: Compression test and check of fuel injectors could be good things to do.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Have you replaced the ignition wires yet? You said you've replaced the sparkplugs, but the wires could also be at fault and cause the same basic issue (no spark in the cylinder). You can check them by doing a [resistance test](https://axleaddict.com/auto-repair/Checking-spark-plug-wires-using-two-simple-strategies).

Comment: Let me add, that sparks are produced (I saw the spark), but only one of the sparkplugs doesn't give power to the engine. Whenever you disconnect the wire it makes no difference

Comment: Test the wires. Also, a spark plug can produce a spark in normal atmosphere, but not produce spark when under pressure during the compression cycle. If there is a weak link anywhere in the electrical chain, it can easily fail to produce a spark. If there is too much resistance in one of the wires, yet it has continuity, you can be sitting in just this situation.

Comment: BTW - Your English is fine! I've been able to understand you without issue ... hopefully you can do the same of us. If something we say doesn't make sense, please ask and we'll explain.

Comment: Thanks your help, I will even see if the fuel injectors are ok.